# How can I get the exact value minimum of this function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to find min of the function 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2
   x^2+\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)
   x+3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2
   x^2+\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)
   x+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}
   \left(2 x^2+2 x+1\right)}.$$
I know, the exact value minimum is $\sqrt{3}$ at $x = 0$. With *Mathematica*, I tried

```
A = 1/Sqrt[2 x^2 + (3 + Sqrt[3]) x + 3] + 
  1/Sqrt[2 x^2 + (3 - Sqrt[3]) x + 3] + Sqrt[(2 x^2 + 2 x + 1)/3]
NMinimize[A, {x}]
```

And I got

> {1.73205, {x -> -2.57345*10^-16}}

When I tried

```
A = 1/Sqrt[2 x^2 + (3 + Sqrt[3]) x + 3] + 
  1/Sqrt[2 x^2 + (3 - Sqrt[3]) x + 3] + Sqrt[(2 x^2 + 2 x + 1)/3]
Minimize[A, {x}]
```

my computer ran about 20 minutes and I did not got the result. How can I get the exact value minimum of the given function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can find minimum by comparing values at zero derivates:

```
TakeSmallestBy[{A /. #, #} & /@ Solve[D[A, x] == 0, x, Reals], First, 1]
```

> {{Sqrt[3], {x -> 0}}}

`TakeSmallestBy` is a v10.1 function similar to `MinimalBy`, but performs numerical comparisons.

Comment: Or `First@MinimalBy[First][{A /. #, #} & /@ Solve[D[A, x] == 0, x, Reals]]` for 10.0.x users.

Comment: @Taiki The problem with `MinimalBy` is that it doesn't perform the comparison numerical order, but instead by using `OrderedQ` ordering. Of course there are correct ways to do this in pre-v10.1 versions too, but they're a bit awkward (`Sort`ing with `Less` as comparison function, or such)...

Comment: I can't see why it's a problem here. The canonical order of `First[e_i]` is by numerical magnitude anyway.

Comment: @Taiki Order given by `MinimalBy` is correct by sheer luck in this case. Consider `MinimalBy[x /. Solve[D[A, x] == 0, x, Reals], Identity, 3] // N` `(* {0., -2.14393, -1.20441} *)` - from this its' obvious you can't trust `MinimalBy` to give numerically sorted ordering of symbolic expressions.

Comment: Oh right... you meant that `MinimalBy` wouldn't evaluate `Root`? Yeah the result is indeed correct by luck here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FindInstance` to find some of the exact stationary points, when mathematica can't solve the equation:

```
FindInstance[Evaluate[D[A, x]] == 0, x]
(*{{x -> 0}}*)
```

Comment: Did you mean `FindInstance[D[A, x] == 0, x]`? But still it takes too long.

Comment: @Taiki Yes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
a[x_] := Sqrt[1 + 2 x + 2 x^2]/Sqrt[3] + 1/Sqrt[
  3 + (3 - Sqrt[3]) x + 2 x^2] + 1/Sqrt[3 + (3 + Sqrt[3]) x + 2 x^2]

Plot[a[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
extr = NSolve[a'[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -2.14393}, {x -> -1.20438}, {x -> 0.}}

```
{a[x] /. #, #} & /@ extr
```

> {{2.42668, {x -> -2.14393}}, {3.4091, {x -> -1.20438}}, \ {1.73205, {x
>   -> 0.}}}

Comment: `0.` is not exact.